# Libertine and TIPA Sans Serif

Tags: fonts, linguistics, libertine, tipa

My goal is to get the `tipass` (that is, TIPA Sans Serif) font to work with the `libertine` package. Using the following, I get computer modern (as expected) with TIPA sans serif:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
This is a test document\\
\textsf{\textipa{a A B b C c D d E e F f G g N n}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, when I add the libertine package, `\usepackage{libertine}`, then I get the `\textsf` command no long works how I want it to:

[image]

I suspect this has something to do with how the `libertine` package sets `\textsf` to Linux Biolinum, which isn't what I want. To get `tipass` for use with IPA, I tried the following code, to no avail, as it complains that the `tipass` font isn't found:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tipa}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{T3}{tipass}{m}{n}
\begin{document}
This is a test document\\
\textsf{\textipa{a A B b C c D d E e F f G g N n}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `\textipa` just executes `\tipaencoding` in a group, which resolves to `\fontencoding{T3}\selectfont`. Add to it `\fontfamily{cmss}` and you're done.

I used `\DeclareTextFontCommand` so `\textipa` becomes robust, which is not by default.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tipa}

\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textipa}{%
  \fontfamily{cmss}\tipaencoding
}
\renewenvironment{IPA}{\fontfamily{cmss}\tipaencoding}{}

\begin{document}
This is a test document

\textipa{a A B b C c D d E e F f G g N n}

\begin{IPA}a A B b C c D d E e F f G g N n\end{IPA}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As outlined in the documentation (p.2) you can load `libertine` with the `rm` option to activate it for the Roman font without activating the Biolinum font.  (Similar options exist for the mono font etc.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rm]{libertine}
\usepackage{tipa}
\begin{document}
This is a test document\\
\textsf{\textipa{a A B b C c D d E e F f G g N n}}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 4):

You don't want the tipass family (tipass is only the name of the font file) but cmss:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{tipa}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{T3}{cmss}{m}{n}

\begin{document}
This is a test document\\
\textipa{a A B b C c D d E e F f G g N n}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But this will use this family for all tipa code. If you want a more sophisticated setup you should write some fd-files.